# CSS Line Height - bottom only

Tags: html, css

Ok, I am quite new to frontend development so please be nice if this is a dumb question :)

I understand that this may not be possible but when applying `line-height` to an element say an `h1`, the `line-height` applies extra space to both the `top` and `bottom` of that element.

This kind of makes sense, but i only want `line-height` to be applied to the bottom of the element so the tops of my `h1, h2` etc can be alined perfectly with other elements.

This jsfiddle shows the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/zja4c/1/

This jsfiddle shows what i want to achieve but am forced to use negative margins: http://jsfiddle.net/25UTA/

The `h1` with `background colour` of red aligns correctly to the top of the left `div`, but the text doesnt.

My question is therefore, is there a way to:

1. Apply `line-height` to only the bottom of an element or,
2. Align an element to the top of the space created by applying `line-height` somehow

Comment: you want only 1st line to be aligned top?

Comment: Line-height Crop — a simple CSS formula to remove top space from your text: https://medium.com/codyhouse/line-height-crop-a-simple-css-formula-to-remove-top-space-from-your-text-9c3de06d7c6f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `line-height` is your only option if you wish to maintain proper spacing across line-breaks. Padding will occur on the bottom of the block-level `H1` element, as you pointed out. I think negative margins are your best bet, but you'll have to fine-tune it line up perfectly with a 50px `line-height`:

http://jsfiddle.net/25UTA/1/

If negative margins can't be used for some reason, you can use relative positioning and a negative `top` value to achieve a similar effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/25UTA/2/

Using `em`'s or percentage font-sizes and line-heights might make this eaiser.

Comment: This is my problem: i want line spacing to occur, just not above the element.  Is there no way to vertically align the text to top?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to vertically align within the line-height. I've updated my answer with another method, but it's pretty much the same effect as negative margins.

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers reference elements with their `display` set to `inline`.

`Line-height` is a setting that refers to `inline` elements. Every answer so far has referred to using padding and margin, which don't work with `inline` styled text.

You can modify the positioning of text within its line with `vertical-align`. Here's a link to an article that goes into copious detail about the property and how it works:

http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to make the line-height 70% and add a little bit of bottom padding.

```css
p, h2 {
  line-height:70%;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could forget line height completely and use padding-bottom:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zja4c/14/)

Comment: This kind of works, but will not allow me to get the properties of line spacing i.e. spacing between lines

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge its not possible to apply `line-height` only for `bottom` using css.

So you can try with `padding` as user1538100 said.